Acccess host localhost from inside a Docker container
So I have VPS that exposes an API endpoint on localhost at port 8080.
I have a Svelte app that must need the endpoint. To build the svelte app I'm using docker-compose.yaml with
version: '3.8'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      target: development
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development

and inside the frontend folder I have the Docker file
FROM node:23-alpine as development

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev", "--", "--host"]

FROM node:23-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine as production
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

With this setup, the Svelteapp seems unable to access the local host on the host machine. The only way I was able to access it was to add the line network_mode: host to the docker-compose. yaml. In this way, I was able to access the localhost IP of the host directly with 192.168.1.17, which is the IP on my whole local network.
Is there a way to access the localhost host IP directly using localhost keyword from the container or just no hard-coding the IP which could change

Related question: from your local machine, is there a way to use localhost to refer to the VPS?  Why doesn't this work, and what problems could it introduce if you tried to hack around it?

There's no way, except network_mode: host, to reach the host using the localhost name. That's because when a container is on a Docker network (the default behavior), the container has it's own IP address and localhost means the container itself.
On a Docker bridge network, the main gateway is the host. You can add a name for it using extra_hosts and the special name host-gateway. It's common practice to use the hostname host.docker.internal as the name you use.
So change your docker-compose.yml file to
version: '3.8'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      target: development
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development

Now you can access the host from inside the container by using the hostname host.docker.internal.

I've now CORS issues but this answers to my question

Canonical question: From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?
